# How to find if a word has all vowels (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Words VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t 
    SELECT 'Stack Overflow' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EQUATORIAL'

SELECT * FROM @t 
WHERE Words  LIKE '%[AEIOU]%'
```

I am getting both as the output

**Words**

```
Stack Overflow
EQUATORIAL
```

The desired output being `EQUATORIAL`

Thanks

Comment: So you're having an issue with collation affecting case sensitivity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the simplest version would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM @t 
WHERE Words LIKE '%A%'
AND Words LIKE '%E%'
AND Words LIKE '%I%'
AND Words LIKE '%O%'
AND Words LIKE '%U%'
```

Answer (score 1):

... like %a% and like %e% .... is the only SQL way I know of.  Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a [CLR SQL Server function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28VS.80%29.aspx) that uses a [regular expression](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html)?

Answer (score 0):

It is because like %[AEIOU]% is true if the word contains any one of them not all of them see Aaronaught or No Refunds for solution.